# Table using div tags

Tags: html, css

How to create table using div tags such that columns in a row should take the width based on available space in the column div.

In below code, first row 3 columns should take available width.

```
<style>
    .tabl {
        width:400px; 
        height:400px;
        border:5px solid blue;
        display:table
    }
    .row {
        height:200px;
        display:table-row; 
        clear:both;
    }
    .cell {
        border:1px solid black;
        display:table-cell
    }
</style>
<div class="tabl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"> CELL one</div>
        <div class="cell"> CELL two</div>
        <div class="cell"> CELL three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"> CELL one</div>
        <div class="cell"> CELL two</div>
        <div class="cell"> CELL three</div>
        <div class="cell"> CELL four</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not how a table works. In each column, all cells have the same width. Make two tables, or just abandon tables altogether and use inline-blocks.

Comment: why using css-way to create a table? Why not using a table, because that is what you try to accomplish?

Comment: Just use a table and style it using CSS, you can use % values in CSS to make the columns a percent of the width of the table, I think. Although Personally I never really use tables.

Comment: @Terradon With HTML tables, the problem is the same: all cells in a column have the same width. (Unless you give one cell a colspan, but I'm not sure that's what the OP is after.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution can be this, with jquery;

```js
var rows = $('.row').length;
var widthrow = parseInt(100, 10) / parseInt(rows, 10);


$('.row').each(function(i, obj) {

  $(this).outerHeight(widthrow+'%'); 
  var count = $(this).children().length;
  var w = parseInt(100, 10) / parseInt(count, 10);

  $(this).children('div').each(function(i, obj) {

    $(this).outerWidth(w+'%');
  });

});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
.tabl {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
.row {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">CELL one</div>
    <div class="cell">CELL two</div>
    <div class="cell">CELL three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">CELL one</div>
    <div class="cell">CELL two</div>
    <div class="cell">CELL three</div>
    <div class="cell">CELL four</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">CELL one</div>
    <div class="cell">CELL two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using Bootstrap? It utilizes 12 column grid system? I won't encourage the use of tables in Web Design today. You can find everything you need to know on the bootstrap website. http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: Columns in a row are dynamic. So adding bootstrap (12 column grid system) classes based on no of cols in row is not possible because we may get 'n' no of columns.